# Change value of attribute Javascript way

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem here, or more like confused. So I know the basics of changing attribute in html via javascript. For example:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" width="610px">
```

So to change the attribute of width for element with id "iframe" would be:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("width", "700px");
```

But how can I change attribute via javascript when it comes like this way? (notice the difference between width's attribute)

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" width=610>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can I change attribute via javascript when it comes like this way?

Exactly the same:

```
.setAttribute("width", "700px");
```

or

```
.setAttribute("width", "700");
```

or

```
.setAttribute("width", 700);
```

Note that all attribute values are considered to be strings anyways. The HTML syntax just allows you to omit quotation marks in certain circumstances, but that doesn't change the datatype. From the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2):

> By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39).
>
> [...]
>
> In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45), periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons (ASCII decimal 58). We recommend using quotation marks even when it is possible to eliminate them.

If you look at the [DOM API specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082), you can see that `setAttribute` is defined to accept a `DOMString` as argument. The JavaScript implementation will convert any value you pass to this method accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way. Although, in your second example, you didn't set the the `id` properly.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" width=610>
<--       ^ added equal sign here                              -->
```

With that change your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FECq3/

Comment: @Natsume you should have been seeing this error in your javascript console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of null` which tells you that you arent finding the element you want.  Read your errors!

Comment: lol sorry I was typing them in notepad for those examples. I was completely forgot about int & String till Emissary mentioned about them xD