# Using replace() for a changing value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a site to see how long until my next class and what it is and I am using some css to give it a "glitch effect"

**Here is the css:**

```css
.glitch {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  /* Animation provies a slight random skew. Check bottom of doc for more information on how to random skew. */
  animation: glitch-skew 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
.glitch::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 2px;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 #ff00cc;
  /* Creates an initial clip for our glitch. This works in a typical top,right,bottom,left fashion and creates a mask to only show a certain part of the glitch at a time. */
  clip: rect(44px, 450px, 56px, 0);
  /* Runs our glitch-anim defined below to run in a 5s loop, infinitely, with an alternating animation to keep things fresh. */
  animation: glitch-anim 5s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
.glitch::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 #00c8ff, 2px 2px #ff00cc;
  animation: glitch-anim2 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

*FULL CSS: [link](https://gist.github.com/ashercs/e55d60ea5d51775e328e40d9941f711e)*

**In the html there is this part:**

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1 class="glitch" data-text="test">test</h1>
        <h2 class="glitch" data-text="time">time</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to edit the the actual text but not the `data-text` value. For the first one it works just fine since I just use this:

```html
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('test', jsonData['schedule'][0][day.toLowerCase()][0][checkperiod()[0]])
```

I come across the issue when using a sort of "countdown" thing to see how long until the next period. I cannot use `replace()` because what I would need to replace changes every second. My current ideas are either just replacing that part with some JavaScript or find a way to replace it as long as it fits the format (2 numbers a colon then 2 numbers). My issue is I am not sure how I would do this any ideas?

**What it is currently doing:**

[image]

(has the minutes and seconds but with the text "time" behind it.)

(this is just a still image it is moving.)

**What I would like it to do:**

[image]

(this is just a still image it is moving.)

Also if I remove where the time normally is it will not have the effect, it just needs to be changed.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I don't understand why you are using replace in the first place.  Can't you just set the innerHTML of the H1?

Comment: @James the issue is that it won't change `data-text="test"` to what I want it to. of course I could use innerHTML normally but not in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change value of attribute Javascript way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343147/change-value-of-attribute-javascript-way)

Comment: The information you provided doesn't even attempt to change that `data-text` attribute. Just use `document.getElementById('wrapper').firstElementChild.setAttribute('data-set',jsonData['schedule'][0][day.toLowerCase()][0][checkperiod()[0]])`

Comment: @MosiaThabo Yes I already tried to and I stated that. I didn't know how to do it what did you want me to put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the h1, and set the data-text to the new value, you can also set the innerHTML at the same time.

```
const theH1 = document.getElementById("wrapper").children[0];  
// it's the first element child of the wrapper div

const theTime = "00:00:00";

theH1.dataset.text = theTime;
theH1.innerHTML = theTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the element attribute value for dataset `data-text` using `Element.setAttribute(AttributeName, AttributeValue)`..

Here's an example, but in your case you should use `jsonData['schedule'][0][day.toLowerCase()][0][checkperiod()[0]]` as the attribute value.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("wrapper").firstElementChild;

element.setAttribute('data-text','00:00');
```

```css
.glitch {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  /* Animation provies a slight random skew. Check bottom of doc for more information on how to random skew. */
  animation: glitch-skew 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
.glitch::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 2px;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 #ff00cc;
  /* Creates an initial clip for our glitch. This works in a typical top,right,bottom,left fashion and creates a mask to only show a certain part of the glitch at a time. */
  clip: rect(44px, 450px, 56px, 0);
  /* Runs our glitch-anim defined below to run in a 5s loop, infinitely, with an alternating animation to keep things fresh. */
  animation: glitch-anim 5s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
.glitch::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  text-shadow: -2px 0 #00c8ff, 2px 2px #ff00cc;
  animation: glitch-anim2 1s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1 class="glitch" data-text="test">test</h1>
        <h2 class="glitch" data-text="time">time</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```